# OpenOffice Writer, deleting text between two text fields

Tags: c#, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

Working with old program for creating reports with Open Office writer. In the program text inserts between two text fields named ''. Now I need to rewrite text between this text fields. Code is:

```
//Method GetTextField() geting text field by name
XTextField xtf=GetTextField(fieldName);

XTextRange rng = xtf.getAnchor().getEnd();

rng.setString("");
rng.setString(attr);
```

This code just insert more text without rewriting. How can I rewrite text? Maybe I should use TextCursor? But I can't figure out how I can set start and end position for TextCursor or TextRange.

Also I can't rewrite this to another way of inserting text, because there are a lot of templates.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `.getEnd()` with `.getText()`?